# What's wrong with this proof about power sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

As an exercise, I was given the task to prove that $$ \mathcal{P}(A) \cup \mathcal{P}(B) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A \cup B). $$

Wanting to do it in the most rigorous way possible, I used the logical definitions and passages as simple as possible, and this is what I've come up with:

$ x \in \mathcal{P}(A) \cup \mathcal{P}(B) \Leftrightarrow x \in \mathcal{P}(A) \  \lor x \in \mathcal{P}(B) \Leftrightarrow x \subseteq A \ \lor x \subseteq B \Leftrightarrow $

$ \Leftrightarrow \forall y (y \in x \Rightarrow y \in A) \ \lor \ \forall y (y\in x \Rightarrow y \in B) \color{red}{ \boldsymbol\Leftrightarrow } \forall y (y\in x \Rightarrow y \in A \ \lor y \in B) \Leftrightarrow $

$ \Leftrightarrow \forall y (y\in x \Rightarrow y \in A \cup B) \Leftrightarrow x \subseteq A \cup B \Leftrightarrow x \in \mathcal{P}(A \cup B).$

All of this seems to prove that $ \forall x(x \in \mathcal{P}(A) \cup \mathcal{P}(B) \Leftrightarrow x \in \mathcal{P}(A \cup B)) $ or equivalently that $ \mathcal{P}(A) \cup \mathcal{P}(B) = \mathcal{P}(A \cup B) $, so I asked myself "Why does the exercise only ask to prove half of it?", and I rapidly realized that, for example, $ A \cup B $ is always an element of $\mathcal{P}(A \cup B) $, but it's not generally a subset of $A$ or $B$, so it's not necessarily an element in $\mathcal{P}(A) \cup \mathcal{P}(B)$.

So I think there must be a mistake in my procedure. I highlighted in red the passage I'm not confident with, but I don't understand why it should be wrong.

Comment: On line two you have y is in x implies y is in A (FOR ALL Y) or y is in x implies y is in B (FOR ALL Y) . This is very different for y is in A or B (A U B) for all y which you have in line 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not true that :

> $\forall x (Px \lor Qx) \leftrightarrow (\forall x Px \lor \forall x Qx)$.

Consider the counter-example: "every (natural) number is either *odd* or *even*".

This is : $\forall n (\text {Odd}(n) \lor \text {Even}(n))$.

But it is not true that : "either all numbers are odd or all numbers are even".

---

Thus the "central" step in your proof must be :

> $(∀y(y∈x ⇒ y∈A) ∨ ∀y(y∈x ⇒ y∈B)) ⇒ ∀y(y∈x ⇒ (y∈A ∨y∈B))$.

As you corectly say, the fact that $\mathcal P(A∪B) \nsubseteq \mathcal P(A) ∪ \mathcal P(B)$ is another counter-example for the above equivalence.

Comment: @MarcoCappai - the other "direction" is provable in every logical calculus. Intuitively, we know that every objcet $x$ is $P$ or every object is $Q$ : $\forall xP \lor \forall xQ$. Consider now an object $a$ whatever: accoding to the previous fact, it must be eitehr a $P$ or a $Q$; i.e. $P(a) \lor Q(a)$. But if this is true for an object whatever, it will be true for **every** objcet. Thus : $\forall x(Px \lor Qx)$.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example where the notation obscures the content. "Rigorous" means "utterly convincing", not "expressed using the smallest alphabet of symbols".

You're right that your red step is wrong. The problem is that you've squashed the two independent "for all $y$" expressions together.

Consider the following plain-English statements: "for all dogs, if the dog is red then it's big", and "for all dogs, if the dog is red then it's small". I can express them more Englishily as "all red dogs are big" and "all red dogs are small" respectively.

You're asserting that the logical-Or of those two is equivalent to "all red dogs are either big or small", which is clearly a false equivalence: there are both big and small dogs, so "all red dogs are big or small" can hold even if "all red dogs are big" and "all red dogs are small" are both false.

Comment: @MarcoCappai A bit of a word of caution:  a human is more likely to make an error reducing a theorem to an unfamiliar language of "self evident truths" than he is to make an error just using intuition in many cases.  You should have an informal proof in mind before you attempt to construct a formal proof.  Further, as a matter of practicality, theorems don't follow from axioms (historically) as much as axioms follow from theorems:  the theorems are often more self evident than the axioms, which in modern days are chosen more for utility than for being self evident.